# Getting corresponding column name from their index in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to map a column name from a table to it's corresponding index(position) number in the same table. So here is what I have.

I have a normal data table which has 320 features. Each feature has a column name. Now I run my machine learning algorithm and the result is stored in another table which has just one row as follows:

```
Features    Features_selected   Coeff_all   Coef_selected
{[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52],[53] (...)  {[23],[26],[49],[57],[72],[76],[77],[78],[80],[102],[142],[146],[148],[151],[155],[203],[236],[237]}    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.00506647638801,0,0,0.00214173291413,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0125487796757,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.0611439140518,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0551106356256,0,0,0,0.0229294880725,0.0870627454718 (...)  {-0.00506647638801,0.00214173291413,0.0125487796757,-0.0611439140518,0.0551106356256,0.0229294880725,0.0870627454718,0.239468263125,0.0440983220954,0.0575895639153,0.0027274832634,0.00682172962834,0.00932203929069,0.00697528972051,0.0333308071579,0.2709655 (...)
```

As you see it has the following columns.

Features- this is of the form of array of list where each list is the index of the column in the original data table. This column should give 320 feature indices.

Features_selected: This column has only those features which are selected for the model. Again an array of feature indices

Coef_all: Weights/coefficients of all the features. Again there is a 1-1 correspondence of each weight in this array with each feature in features array.

Coef_selected: only non zero coefficients.

Now I run this query on this result data to unnest each features as instead of one row I would get 320 rows with each row having the indices of each feature along with the corresponding coefficient.

The code and the resilient output is shown in the below image.

[image]

So now I have a list of feature indices with their corresponding coefficients, but I want to map each feature indices with the actual column name. As mentioned above the actual column name are present in the original base table which has the whole data. Can we use the information schema of that table and get the corresponding feature name with indices.?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the structure the concerned tables here? Where do we get the name from? And how is that table linked to this table? Also, please don't post images.

Comment: Updated. pls check again. Also please remove the close tag . I think I have provided decent info now

Answer (score 0):

You can try your luck using

```
SELECT column_name, ordinal_position
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = '<schema_name>'
AND table_name   = '<table_name>';
```

with the corresponding schema and table name. The **oridnal_position** value refers to your index and the **column_name** is the name of the column at this index.

---

An alternative solution, which micht be better than mine, is provided [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22420).